# iphone switch on/off bluetooth programmatically

Tags: iphone, bluetooth

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any way to switch on/off bluetooth in iPhone programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6594947/is-there-any-way-to-switch-on-off-bluetooth-in-iphone-programmatically)

Is there a way to code for switching bluetooth ON/OFF for iPhone, which is acceptable for AppStore?

I want to switch ON/OFF bluetooth in my app, but I heard that AppStore rejects the applications which used private framework for this purpose. Is there any acceptable way of achieving this? Please provide me a guid/sample if it's possible.

The CoreBluetooth.framework that I can add as link library, does that works for all iOS versions?

Answer (score 0):

No. There's no way.

You can sort of turn it on in code by calling various `GKSession` things to create a peer network, but that is then iOS asking to turn on bluetooth as a result of that call.

But you can't turn it on and off in your own code in a way that will be accepted