# iPhone : how to auto connect to a known wifi SSID?

Tags: iphone, ios, wifi, ssid, captivenetwork

I know it is possible to list the available Wifi networks on iPhone using the CaptiveNetwork API from official Apple SDK.

I was wondering if there is a way to auto connect to a specific SSID programmatically as long  as I can find it in the list returned by CaptiveNetwork ?

Answer (score 5):

Apple would not like you to do such things. Connecting to Wifi Stations is the responsibility of the user, so don't expect a public API. See e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10231735/is-there-a-way-to-toggle-wifi-on-and-off-programatically-in-ios). Probably the makers of [this](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/autowifi-lite/id301447456?mt=8) app also would like to do it automatically.

Peter

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I don't think you will be able to get the list of available WiFi networks on iPhone using Captive network API. It will just give you the details of your connected wifi. And though there is private APIs to do this, Apple doesn't approve the apps that use them.

Answer (score 1):

As I know, you only could get the current-connected wifi without using private api, but what confusing me is Nest iOS App do could get a list of available wifi, and Apple didn't reject it!!!

Comment: Is this still possible with recent versions of the Nest app?

Comment: Yes, still possible. I have figured out how Nest App achieve this:
First, nest app should connect to the AP of Nest device(which contains a wifi module), and then the nest device will pass the wifi list to nest app.