# How to turn On and Off Wi-Fi in Xamarin Form for (Android and iOS)?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

Currently, i am using the plugin.Connectivity from nuggets in visual studio 2015.I am able to see the current status of the Wi-Fi but I am not able to Turn On and Off Wifi access point.Anyone any idea?

Answer (score 2):

The Connectivity plugin is to detect the connection status only. It does not have feature to turn on/off the WiFi. To modify the WiFi status:

**Android**: Refer to [How to enable/disable WiFi from an application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674333/how-to-enable-disable-wifi-from-an-application)

**iOS**: Not possible for non jailbroken device.

Answer (score 0):

On iOS it's simply not possible, you can use private API but most probably your app will be rejected by Apple : 
[Is there a way to toggle wifi on and off programatically in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10231735/is-there-a-way-to-toggle-wifi-on-and-off-programatically-in-ios)

On Android it's possible with use of [WifiManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html).
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/13604/how-do-i-turn-on-off-the-wifi-access-point 
[Android: How to Enable/Disable Wifi or Internet Connection Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930990/android-how-to-enable-disable-wifi-or-internet-connection-programmatically)

P.S.: Please use search before posting new questions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.Now I am using WifiManager in visual studio 2015 using xamarin form. WifiManager doesn't exist in the current context.how to solve this in VS2015 ?