# iOS 5.1 toggle Bluetooth by BluetoothManager

Tags: iphone, ios5, frameworks, bluetooth

I want to try out the BluetoothManager. But I am really confused after reading and testing all the entries here.

First, I found in

```
Xcode/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BluetoothManager.framework
```

the needed Framework. But there was only the binarie file there. So I add a "Headers" folder and put the [BluetoothManager.h](http://iphone-dev.googlecode.com/svn/branches/include-1.2-sdk/include/BluetoothManager/) file in it.

In my project, I add this framework, but it couldn't find any BluetoothManager.h file, so I get an error, if I use

```
#import "BluetoothManager.h"
```

or

```
#import <BluetoothManager/BluetoothManager.h>
```

I want to use the following code to start BT:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
    exit( EXIT_SUCCESS ) ;
#else
    /* this works in iOS 4.2.3 */
    Class BluetoothManager = objc_getClass( "BluetoothManager" ) ;
    id btCont = [BluetoothManager sharedInstance] ;
    [btCont setPowered:YES] ;
#endif
    return YES ;
}
```

I had tried also all the ideas here:

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743610/programmatically-turn-on-bluetooth-in-the-iphone-sdk)
or
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518406/is-there-a-way-to-toggle-bluetooth-and-or-wifi-on-and-off-programatically-in-ios)
or 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518406/is-there-a-way-to-toggle-bluetooth-and-or-wifi-on-and-off-programatically-in-ios)

Has any one a realy good idea, a tutorial or a really running example for using (PrivateFramework/)BluetoothManager to toggle Bluetooth on iPhone, SKD 5.1?

Thank you very much.

isicom

Answer (score 3):

You can generate the header files using class-dump tools from github

Or copy/paste the below content(I generated for IOS 5.1) into BluetoothManager.h and add that file in your project. Then you should not see the error.

---

```
@class NSMutableDictionary;

@interface BluetoothManager : NSObject
{
    struct BTLocalDeviceImpl *_localDevice;
    struct BTSessionImpl *_session;
    int _available;
    BOOL _audioConnected;
    BOOL _scanningEnabled;
    BOOL _scanningInProgress;
    unsigned int _scanningServiceMask;
    struct BTDiscoveryAgentImpl *_discoveryAgent;
    struct BTPairingAgentImpl *_pairingAgent;
    struct BTAccessoryManagerImpl *_accessoryManager;
    NSMutableDictionary *_btAddrDict;
    NSMutableDictionary *_btDeviceDict;
}

+ (id)sharedInstance;
+ (int)lastInitError;
- (BOOL)available;
- (id)init;
- (BOOL)_attach:(id)arg1;
- (BOOL)_setup:(struct BTSessionImpl *)arg1;
- (void)_cleanup:(BOOL)arg1;
- (void)dealloc;
- (void)_postNotificationWithArray:(id)arg1;
- (void)_postNotification:(id)arg1;
- (void)postNotification:(id)arg1;
- (void)postNotificationName:(id)arg1 object:(id)arg2;
- (void)postNotificationName:(id)arg1 object:(id)arg2 error:(id)arg3;
- (int)powerState;
- (BOOL)powered;
- (BOOL)enabled;
- (BOOL)setPowered:(BOOL)arg1;
- (BOOL)setEnabled:(BOOL)arg1;
- (void)_powerChanged;
- (BOOL)isAnyoneScanning;
- (id)addDeviceIfNeeded:(struct BTDeviceImpl *)arg1;
- (void)_removeDevice:(id)arg1;
- (BOOL)wasDeviceDiscovered:(id)arg1;
- (BOOL)deviceScanningEnabled;
- (BOOL)deviceScanningInProgress;
- (void)resetDeviceScanning;
- (void)_scanForServices:(unsigned int)arg1 withMode:(int)arg2;
- (void)scanForServices:(unsigned int)arg1;
- (void)scanForConnectableDevices:(unsigned int)arg1;
- (void)setDeviceScanningEnabled:(BOOL)arg1;
- (void)_restartScan;
- (void)_setScanState:(int)arg1;
- (void)_discoveryStateChanged;
- (BOOL)isDiscoverable;
- (void)setDiscoverable:(BOOL)arg1;
- (BOOL)devicePairingEnabled;
- (void)setDevicePairingEnabled:(BOOL)arg1;
- (void)cancelPairing;
- (void)unpairDevice:(id)arg1;
- (id)pairedDevices:(BOOL)arg1;
- (id)pairedDevices;
- (id)pairedLEDevices;
- (void)setPincode:(id)arg1 forDevice:(id)arg2;
- (void)acceptSSP:(int)arg1 forDevice:(id)arg2;
- (void)connectDevice:(id)arg1 withServices:(unsigned int)arg2;
- (void)connectDevice:(id)arg1;
- (BOOL)connectable;
- (void)setConnectable:(BOOL)arg1;
- (id)connectingDevices;
- (id)connectedDevices;
- (BOOL)_onlySensorsConnected;
- (BOOL)connected;
- (void)_connectedStatusChanged;
- (void)_connectabilityChanged;
- (BOOL)audioConnected;
- (void)setAudioConnected:(BOOL)arg1;
- (void)startVoiceCommand:(id)arg1;
- (void)endVoiceCommand:(id)arg1;
- (BOOL)isServiceSupported:(unsigned int)arg1;
- (void)enableTestMode;

@end
```

---

Comment: It also works on iOS 6 and the new iOS 7 beta! Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm using this code BOOL currentState = [btCont enabled] ;
    [btCont setEnabled:!currentState] ; This shows me error like Multiple method named setEnbled: in iOS 7

Comment: For those errors just type cast that :

[(BluetoothManager *)btCont setEnabled:!currentState];