# Turn on Bluetooth programmatically in iphone giving error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, bluetooth

I want to switch on bluetooth grammatically in iPhone. This is my code for that --

```
Class BluetoothManager = objc_getClass("BluetoothManager");
id btCont = [BluetoothManager sharedInstance];
[btCont setPowered:YES];
```

I put the .header files under Header flolder under following path :

/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BluetoothManager.framework/Headers

But the problem is that its giving me an error i.e. : 'BluetoothManager/BluetoothManager.h' file not found

So please let me know if I done something wrong here.

I found this all stuff from following link :

[Programmatically turn on bluetooth in the iphone sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743610/programmatically-turn-on-bluetooth-in-the-iphone-sdk)

Thank you very much 
In advance.

Comment: Hi, I put all header files in the project and then import and add header file like "BluetoothManager.h" so that error is removed but now one warning is there : Implicitly declaring C library function 'objc_getClass' with type 'id(const char*)'. App is running now but it never makes bluetooth turn on. If you know anything the please tell me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with finding trying various things, I found the simple way to trun on bluetooth with "GameKit" framework.

Steps to implement :

1. Add the GameKit framework to your project.
2. Import class to your project -- #import GameKit/GameKit.h>
3. create object of GKPeerPickerController
   GKPeerPickerController *connectionPicker;
4. Paste this code in viewDidLoad

   connectionPicker = [[GKPeerPickerController alloc] init];
   connectionPicker.delegate = self;
   [connectionPicker show];

It showing you the alert popup to turn on bluetooth and clicking on yes you will get the bluetooth on.

But I dont know about the customizing that popup so if anyone knows please let me know.

Thank you in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, just to be sure, you know you can't use that in a shipping app, right?

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10272349/ios-5-1-toggle-bluetooth-by-bluetoothmanager), which explains how to generate the header file you need.

Comment: Hello thank you for your valuable response I modify my file like this only then its never give error but as I mention my 1st comment that warning is still there. So app is running but it never turn on the bluetooth. Any more suggestion's.   
Thank you.