# Import BluetoothManager private framework in IOS

Tags: ios, ios-bluetooth

I need to import the BluetoothManager Private Framework on my IOS 7 . I need to build a test app that would scan / discover and list nearby Bluetooth devices . I referred to the following link mentioned in S.O [iOS 6 - BluetoothManager framework - "NSObject" not found error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14639994/ios-6-bluetoothmanager-framework-nsobject-not-found-error) , however I am unable to import the BluetoothManager.framework folder. In fact when I go to the link library with binary options in Xcode I do not see the BluetoothManager.framework listed at all . Is there something different I need to try for IOS7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [Github tutorial for handling the BluetoothManager framework](https://github.com/michaeldorner/BeeTee). But the steps are basically

- Find the folder, e.g. by terminal

```
open /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BluetoothManager.framework
```

- Extract the Headers.zip archive and add the extracted folder Headers
  which includes `BluetoothManager.h` and `BluetoothDevice.h` in the directory above.
- Restart Xcode Now you will find the `BluetoothManager.framework` in **Targets → YourApp → Build Phases → Link Binary With Libraries**:
  [image]