# access ios device settings

Tags: iphone, ios, nsuserdefaults

Is it possible to change the device settings like wifi, personal hotspot, torch, personal hotspot, turn location services. I want to turn them to on/off from the application only without moving to settings screen. Is this posssible. OR any good tutorial for this?

Comment: are you willing to use private APIs and/or jailbreak the phone?

Comment: in that way is this possible?

Comment: Yes.  Depending on which setting you're talking about, it can be not too difficult, or quite hard.  But, for example, the **SBSettings** app for jailbroken phones does this.  Some source code for *toggles* is available online.  Search for "iPhone bluetooth toggle" or "iPhone brightness toggle", and you'll come up with some results.  Again, it requires private APIs for all of these, and jail breaking for some.

Answer (score 2):

No it is not, you are not able to changes these settings.

Comment: none of them??. ...i have seen an app "Bluetooth" http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bluetooth/id532403238?mt=8 where bluetooth settings are changed from the app.

Comment: Yes and these apps where pulled from the app store because apple does not allow it.

Comment: Just one that slipped by, it will get pulled as soon as some apple employee deems that it should not be Appstore.

Answer (score 1):

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518406/is-there-a-way-to-toggle-bluetooth-and-or-wifi-on-and-off-programatically-in-ios) it is using private API to toggle bluetooth setting. So there is no way to change settings from within app using public SDK. You even cannot open "settings" app programmatically now in ios 5.0.1 and later. My app was using below statement to open settings app but it stopped working when we moved to latest iOS SDK.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs://"]];
```